# Why is the const qualifier in this type alias dropped?

Tags: c++, c++17, qualifiers

## TL;DR

Given the following type:

```
struct A
{
    std::vector<std::string> vec;

    using reference = std::iterator_traits<decltype(vec)::iterator>::reference;
    using const_reference = const reference;
};
```

Why is `reference == const_reference`? Why is the `const` qualifier dropped in the second type alias?

See the example on [godbold](https://godbolt.org/g/Bf3roh) which shouldn't compile.

## Details

I have a templated class that takes a bunch of iterators (-types) as template arguments. From these iterators I need to deduce the reference and const reference type because I have some member functions like:

```
struct A
{
    std::vector<std::string> vec;

    using reference = std::iterator_traits<decltype(vec)::iterator>::reference;
    using const_reference = const reference;

    const_reference foo() const
    {
        return vec[0];
    }
};
```

By dropping the `const` qualifier, I'm effectively returning a reference in `foo` which is illegal because it's a const member function and so the compiler throws.

Comment: `reference` is `string&`. `const reference` is actually `string& const`

Comment: The compiler gives you a pretty explicit warning actually: *"'const' qualifier on reference type 'A::reference' (aka ...) has no effect [-Wignored-qualifiers]"*

Comment: @Peter But `iterator_traits` has no `const_reference` type.

Comment: @Holt Yes I saw that warning but I didn't know *why* it popped up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It *is* dropped. What we call a "const reference" is really a reference to const - `const int&`.

Having an `int&` and adding `const` would make that `int& const`. But such a const is dropped.

Your problem is similar to the difference between `const int*` and `int* const`. Except that for references, `int&` and `int& const` is the same type - the `const` is ignored.

Comment: I find it difficult to believe there is no dupe somewhere.

Comment: There probably is. I started out as a comment, just like you, but it became too large to fit.  :-)

Comment: Well there is probably a duplicate if you phrase the question correctly. But if you don't know the root of the problem it's kinda hard to phrase it correctly.

Comment: @Timo It's obviously not easy to find, but I swear I've seen this question before.

Comment: Would `using const_reference = const std::remove_reference_t<reference>&;` be a qualified alternative or are there some pitfals?

Comment: @Timo - That would probably work. I would have used `std::vector<std::string>::const_reference` and avoided juggling chain saws.

Comment: @BoPersson Yeah I would also use that if I could. But as I wrote in the question, I don't know what iterators I get (they could also be native pointers), that's why I have to use `iterator_traits`.

Comment: So I can think of it as, what the OP is doing is `const (T&)` but what they really want is `(const T)&`. The `remove_reference` trick would work because you can extract the `T` from `(T&)`, add const, then put the reference back.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is west const.  West const is bad const east const is best const.

West const is putting the const on the left of the token you want to be const.  East const is putting it on the right.

If I told you never to put const on the left of your types, and that const always applies to the thing on *its* left, look at this:

```
using const_reference = reference const;
```

you can probably work out why the `const` didn't work.  After expanding reference naively you get `string&const` -- here you attempt to apply `const` to `&` not `string`, and a `foo &const` is not the same as a `foo const&` -- a `foo&const` is just a `foo&` as `const` cannot apply to the reference itself, but only to the type referred to.

Sure, you say, but that is why I want west const!

West const **does the same thing here**.  It applies to the `&` not then `string` and then is discarded.  It just does so in a way that is more confusing and harder to grasp intuitively.

To understand const, convert your const to east const.  West const is just an exception to the standard east const rule, where if there is no token in the type to the left it applies to the token on the right.  The token on the right here is the entire type `string&` bundled into a type alias (type aliases are not macros).  If instead you typed `const string&` the token on the right would be `string` and you'd get `string const&` in sane, east-const style.

East const is best const.

Comment: I don't know why I find this hilarious

Comment: I like the terminology of west and east const :)